# How far should I go to minimize database queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's a description of the data I'm going to pull from a MySQL database for a product page on a current project.

Product data comes from a `product` table, variable names (color, size, etc.) come from a table called `product_option_group`, the actual values for those variables (red, green, blue or small, medium, large, etc.) are in a `product_option` table, and product photos associated with that product are in `product_photo`.

I could probably use `JOIN`-s to create a single query that returns all of that (product, variables, values, photos) in a single query that I would then need to `foreach` the hell out of to make useful.  My question is whether or not that makes any sense. To what extent should I work to minimize queries?

In the case of a list of products I'm using a single query to fetch the small amount of product data and the URL of the first product photo. But on a page showing a single product, I'm a little unsure as to the best approach. Seems like one way I'm writing a crazy long MySQL query and then doing a lot of PHP parsing. And another way I'm making a fistful of database calls.

Which is best?

Comment: When you take into consideration that each mysql call takes x amount of time to contact the mysql server, process the data and return it, then extrapolate for a) loops and b) site traffic...yeah, keep mysql queries to a minimum. Certain frameworks will help you accomplish this (fuelphp, for example).

Comment: `foreach` = 100s of **nano**seconds to few microseconds. Latency of DB query = 20 to 200 **milli**seconds (typically -- could possibly be seconds, minutes, hours if you do complicated stuff on huge datasets). Accessing a database is normally at least 3-4 network round trip times (plus another 3 if you have no connection) plus at least 1-2 seek times (unless the dataset is tiny enough to fit in RAM, which it usually isn't), plus waiting on locks, plus whatever it takes to actually transfer and process the query and the data. You can't get rid of the latter, but you can strip down the former.

Comment: IF product_options and product_photos are 1:1 then you can consider eliminating the need for that table by storing the photo in the options - nullified of course if an option can have n photos ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always been taught (and worked with) the assumption that you should only optimize when needed, and not try to optimize things that aren't causing problems.

So, in your case, take what you've got and run it through the mill -- put a load on it and see how it handles it.  If it's slow, then think about whether you want to try to combine into one query, or add an index or two, or what you might do to speed it up.  Ask yourself if it's the DB which is returning slowly, or if the traffic back and forth between the two is the problem, or if the PHP is not processing it fast enough for you.

Spend your time where it is needed, and remember to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks Ametren. You re-affirmed my feelings. If things are slow once I've loaded up test data and hit it with some traffic I'll look closer. In the meantime, I'm going with KISS.

Comment: @StevenSokulski When talking about db's "KISS" roughly translates to "Normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works."

Answer (score 3):

It is good practice to minimize the number of queries per page load.

However, database servers are good at dealing with many small queries. A lot of CMS's have *hundreds* of queries *per page load*.

So, always try to optimize but don't go crazy with it.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Seems you echo the same sentiment as ametren. Currently, this cart is for a smallish site that'll process maybe 1 or 2 orders a day, so I'm not losing any sleep over scale. Thanks!